# Members only conditional

Tags: members, conditionals, advanced-conditionals

Is there a better way to write this?

```
{if logged_in_group_id == "1" || logged_in_group_id == "6" || logged_in_group_id == "7" || logged_in_group_id == "11"}
Hello Members...
{/if}
```

It seems very long.

Version 2.9.0

Answer (score 1):

To add to Blatant's comprehensive answer and keeping native without PHP...

```
{if "|1|6|7|11|" *= "|".logged_in_group_id."|"} ... {/if}
```

[Advanced Conditionals](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#contains-operator)

Comment: Hi Peter, I would like to keep it native, would it be appropriate to add a snippet with the group_id's eg:

{if "{snippet}" *= "|".logged_in_group_id."|"} ... {/if}

Comment: Yes, that should work as snippets are added before conditionals: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/template_engine.html

Comment: Thank you, will this advanced conditional work in ee2 and what are the benefits of it over my original syntax? I am just trying to better understand, thanks.

Comment: It will only work in EE2.9 or upwards (Ref: https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/new-conditionals-parser-in-2.9). The only benefits from your original is the length and ease of understanding the conditional. There may be fractional performance issues with my suggestion, but I doubt these would be measurable.

Comment: Brilliant, I am on 2.9.0, thanks for help.

Comment: Worth noting, advanced conditionals have been around since 2.3 (from memory) just a new handler with more options (I think `*=` was one of them) in 2.9. Kudos and vote for this answer though, Peter found the conditional I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't say what version of EE you're using, so I'm gonna assume v2, though this solution should work just fine in v3 too.

the quickest method would be PHP's `in_array()` function, which you can use in your template natively, however so that I don't give a PHP answer first here's a plugin that adds in_array to EE :

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/in-array

```
{if '{exp:in_array value=“2” array="1|6|7|11"}'}
  Hello Members...
{/if}
```

If you rather add plugins that should get you there, you can shorten your EE tags as well, as `group_id` will be 0 for non logged in members :

```
{if group_id == '1' || group_id == '6' || group_id == '7' || group_id == '11'}
  Hello Members...
{/if}
```

Or if you're not afraid of a bit o PHP and the parse order :

EE v2.X

```
<?php if ( in_array( ee()->session->userdata('group_id') , array ( 1, 6, 7, 11 ) ) ) { ?>
  Hello Members...
<?php } ?>
```

EE v3.X

```
<?php 
  global $SESS; 
  if ( in_array( $SESS->userdata('group_id') , array ( 1, 6, 7, 11 ) ) ) { 
?>
    Hello Members...
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you for in-depth answer Blatant, this has definitely given me some options